# jQuery plugin isn't reacting in Drupal site

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

On [this page](http://www.bo-medical.com/nl/foto-test) i try to implement [PrettyPhoto](http://untame.net/2013/02/twitter-bootstrap-build-a-responsive-lightbox-gallery/) jQuery lightbox plugin for my Bootstrap 2 website. However the images are not appearing in the lightbox? It looks like the jQuery plugin isn't reacting?

The jQuery file i use are:

- [jquery.prettyPhoto.js](http://www.bo-medical.com/sites/all/themes/bomedical/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js)

and before my closing body i use:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Do i also have to adjust something in the jQuery file `jquery.prettyPhoto.js` to work in Drupal?

**Update:**

I solved the problem! In the `<a href>` it needs the attribute `rel="lightbox[group]"`. But in Drupal `Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats` i had to add the  to `Allowed HTML tags` and turn `Add rel="nofollow" to all links` **OFF**. This solved the problem!

Comment: Hi, questions about general web development are off topic here but can be asked on Stack Overflow. If you have a question related to the Drupal javascript API, rather than a jQuery plugin, please edit the post to clear up exactly what that is. Thanks

Comment: try

   `<script>
    (function ($) {
    
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:''});
      });
    
    })(jQuery);
    </script>`

Comment: @Clive his code is not working because his jQuery is not formatted properly for Drupal.

Comment: @Clive exactly thats why i ask it here. Because out of Drupal i have no problem implementing it... What do i have to do now?

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank Start debugging! "Doesn't work" isn't enough for anyone to be able to help, for obvious reasons - find out what's going wrong, once you've done that and confirmed it's something related to Drupal and not the library or your custom JS, edit the question with the details and it can be re-opened

Comment: @NoSssweat In this case, no - the OP's code is using `jQuery`, not `$`, so no need for the closure. The problem is related to the plugin (see the updated code which even uses behaviours), not Drupal

Comment: @Clive I found the problem. In my update i described the solution which solved the problem. How can i answer this questions myself so its good for my reputation?